# Mongodb cannot use the part (...) to traverse the element ({...: undefined})]

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

After upgrade to 3.0 mongo driver i am receiving some new error on update request. For update like this:

```
db.table.update({_id: .... } , {$set : { "tags.Tag1" : true }});
```

I am receiving

```
cannot use the part (tags of tags.Tag1) to traverse the element ({tags: null})]]
```

The problem is that my updated document already contains default value for `tags` : null. If I manually remove it from document , update starts to work correctly. It is some new behavior for me , and it is happens after updating mongo driver from 2 to 3 ( not even database itself).

But now I wonder now how to avoid this error. I can of course check if "tags" already defined and only then make `$set` to element or the whole map. But it means 3 requests vs one old and the other problems like atomicity.

Answer (score 6):

Although it's an old post but I think what you are looking for is the [$ positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)

I am guessing your "tags" is an array. So the above example could be something like

```
db.table.update({_id: .... } , {$set : { "tags.$.Tag1" : true }});
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be updated... I had resolved similar problem

*Resolved* this

```
db.table.updateById({_id: .... } , {$set : { "levelSpecificData.scale.uom": "feet"}});

5b1f566ed65c7dcc34aaa7d5 MongoError: cannot use the part (scale of levelSpecificData.scale.uom) to traverse the element ({scale: false})
```

where in my collection '***levelSpecificData.scale***' was a **Boolean type T/F**

**I changed the default value type of *levelSpecificData.scale* to '{}' empty object**... Surprisingly it worked fine after changing default values to object, since I want to treat *scale* as an object reference this solution was all good for it.

Comment: actually if scale has true or false value it is pretty reasonable to receive this error.